# How to resize RTF images

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, rtf

I am writing an image to an RTF document using ColdFusion 9 and I want to size the images to a certain size. How would I do that in the RTF? I cannot change the stored image size or make a new one.

```
#reportData.image#\nestcell{\*\nesttableprops\trowd\trgaph108\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\brdrcf1 \trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3
```

Comment: See the [CFImage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7945.html) tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do this on the server side first using cfimage as just `constraining` the image to a particular size in the RTF document (which is what you are really asking in your question) does nothing to reduce the actual physical size of the image. As such, constraining a 1MB image that's 1024x768 to 240x320 in the RTF, still embeds a 1MB image in your file and wastes bandwidth and make opening the document slower.